# Android NFC Phone Automatic Emulation of Multiple Tags

Tags: android, tags, nfc, emulation

So I understand that, in Android, a smart phone can be configured in emulation mode to emulate a given NFC tag. What I'm curious about is whether there is a way to identify an NFC reader through some sort of unique id during the NFC handshake.

For example, let's say I use a few NFC-compatible tags on a daily basis...say a fuel rewards card, my security badge for work, and my major brand credit card. Is it possible to automatically emulate the correct tag based on the reader detected by the phone, so that when I tap at the fuel pump my fuel perks tag is emulated, when I tap the sensor at work my badge is emulated, and when I tap at whatever retail store my credit card is emulated?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Short answer: probably not. Readers do not have unique IDs. They send out polling commands, which are standardized and fixed.

However, contactless smart card systems are often ISO 7816-4 compatible. They support multiple applications on a single card. The readers select the Application IDs of the application they want to interact with. So if all your cards are ISO 14443-4 cards that are ISO 7816-4 compatible, it is (theoretically) possible to combine them into a single card, for example in the secure element of your NFC phone.

Another popular contactless system is MIFARE Classic. The secure element in your NFC phone can very likely emulate a MIFARE Classic card, too. These cards are not ISO 7816-4 compliant, but still have ways of combining multiple applications on a single card (using a so-called MIFARE Application Directory). So if your cards are a collection of ISO 7816-4 compliant cards and MIFARE Classic cards, it is theoretically possible to combine them in the secure element. However, the MIFARE card have limited memory and use secret keys for read and write access, so you cannot read out their content. So even if it may be theoretically possible to combine multiple applications, it may still be impossible in practice.

Very likely, one or more of your cards are not ISO 7816-4 compliant and not MIFARE Classic, but for example MIFARE Ultralight, DESFire or ICODE (to name but a few). You can check what chip is inside with an Android app such as [TagInfo](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.nxp.taginfolite).